# Can't see buttons in ECM 2.0

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-ecm

Just did a fresh install of Sitecore 6.6 rev 130214 (update 4) plus DMS and followed that up with an install of ECM 2.0. (installed SPEAK first as part of ECM)

As I navigate to the campaign manager, I have realized I can't see the button images. e.g., "OK", "Back", "Save", "Cancel", etc.

Using IE's "Developer Tools", I can see that the buttons are supposed to be rendered using PIE, but I just can't see them.

The only way I can see them is if I click and hold on where the button is supposed to be and then drag off the button and release.  It looks like it is maybe showing the 'down' state for the button. (gray)

I'm using IE8. (I know, but it's what my client uses and I am in the process of getting new browsers installed on my client dev machine to see if it's an IE issue)  It doesn't seem to matter if it's IE8 or IE8 in compatibility mode.

Interface looks beautiful, it's just that I can't see all of it. :)

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: What does your developer tools say about the Document mode?

Comment: Document mode is IE8 Standards.  I've tried IE7 standards and quirks mode as well, but both of those totally break the page.  Will hopefully get a new browser installed soon to test again.

Comment: Absolutely. Same thing happens at my end so I would highly recommend IE9. Just out of curiosity what happens in Chrome/Firefox ? Any joy there?

Comment: Did this get resolved in the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I remember ECM 2.0 does not support IE8. It works with IE9.
Try to find the list of supported browsers in ECM documentation.

Comment: Couldn't find a list of supported browsers for ECM 2.0, but once I got other browsers installed (FF), I can see the buttons with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Following from what [Ivan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/550070/ivan-korshun) said,

1. It would be advisable if you read the [IE configuration guide](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/sc62keywords/configure_internet_explorer_sc62_a4.pdf) on SDN.
2. You might have to have Adobe Flash and/or Silverlight installed as well. Silverlight compatibility available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/Get-Started/Install/Default.aspx).
3. Finally also have a read of the [Release Notes](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%206/ReleaseNotes/ChangeLog/Release%20History%20SC66.aspx) of Sitecore CMS and DMS 6.6.0 rev. 130214 (6.6.0 Update-4). Interestingly there is no mention of IE8 explicitly but it highlights the issues, if any, faced with IE9.

Let us know if this was of any help. All the best.